# Serialize several models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am looking to optimize the serialization of multiple models. Currently, I am able to serialize the models through the use of `SerializerMethodField` and providing the needed fields. I would like to use directly the serializer `SiteSchoolSerializer` to fetch in advance the results using `queryset.select_related` to reduce the time of the queries.

I have the models:

```
site.py:

class SchoolDistance(models.Model):
    school_id = models.ForeignKey(School,
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   db_column="school_id",
                                   null=True)
    school_distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=4, blank=False, null=False)

class Site(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    nearest_school = models.ForeignKey(SchoolDistance,
                                        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                        db_column="nearest_school",
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
------------------                                  
location_asset.py:
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    location_type = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['name','location_type']]
        ordering = ("id", )

class School(Location):
   
    description = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    keywords = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id", )
```

With the following serializers:

```
distance.py
class SiteSchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        #school  = SchoolSerializer()
        model = SchoolDistance
        #fields = ('school_id', 'school_distance','school) why failing?
        fields = ('school_id', 'school_distance')

------------------
location_types.py:
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name"
        )
        
--------
get.py:
class SiteGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # nearest_school = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    nearest_school = SiteSchoolSerializer(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = (
            "id",
            "address",
            "nearest_school", #Should include name besides id and distance
        )

    # Want to avoid the below function and use directly SiteSchoolSerializer:
    # def get_nearest_school(self, instance):
    #     nearest_school = None
    #     if instance.nearest_school:
    #         nearest_school = dict()
    #         nearest_school['school_id'] = instance.nearest_school.school_id_id
    #         nearest_school['school_distance'] = instance.nearest_school.school_distance
    #         nearest_school['name'] = School.objects.get(id=nearest_school['school_id']).name
    #     return nearest_school
```

Used by the following View:

```
list.py:
class SiteList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SiteGetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Site.objects.all()
        
        return queryset
        # Want to be able to use select_related
        # Getting the error:
        # django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `school` is not valid for model `SchoolDistance`.
        # when adding school  = SchoolSerializer() to SiteSchoolSerializer
        #return queryset.select_related('nearest_school').order_by('id')
```

Not sure what I am missing in order to use `SiteSchoolSerializer` serializer in `SiteGetSerializer` serializer.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think error that you wrote is caused because of your SchoolDistance model does not have a field named `school`, have you tried setting a serializer field this way?

```
school = SchoolSerializer(source="school_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception happens because you are trying to serialize a non existent field e.g:

```py
class SiteSchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SchoolDistance
        # No such field in you SchoolDistance model
        fields = ('school', ...)
```

That being said, the current code you posted is wokring fine. But in order to have a similar response to your `SerializerMethodField` you would have to override [`.to_representation`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) method:

serializers.py

```py
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.School
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name"
        )

class SiteSchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    school_id = SchoolSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.SchoolDistance
        fields = ('school_id', 'school_distance')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        school_representation = representation.pop('school_id')
        for key, value in school_representation.items():
            representation[key] = value

        return representation

class SiteGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nearest_school = SiteSchoolSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Site
        fields = (
            'id',
            'address',
            'nearest_school',
        )
```

views.py

```py
class SiteList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Site.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SiteGetSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        queryset.select_related('nearest_school')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.data)
```